# RDL build in visual studio 2015 not opening\supported in 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

RDL build in visual studio 2015 not opening\supported in 2012. How to make compatible in old version.

Comment: I didn't think you could "down grade" your report version to be backward compatible!

Comment: That means i need to build fresh report ?

Comment: You could try changing the target server version setting  or change the namespace - it may or may not work. open the RDL in XML and change the following line xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition".. make sure you back up before you try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of SSDT have possibility to set different versions as targets (2005. 2008R2, "2016 and later" etc).

This option is available under Project Configuration properties->General->TargetServerVersion

Consider to update SSDT to latest version ([17.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)), However even older versions have a possibility to downgrade RDL by rebuilding project (right click->rebuild) and copy RDL from the output folder (bin\Debug) if target version was set to a previous release